# Using a micro-SD card with an USB-adapter to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using a micro-SD and an USB adapter. 
Apart from a Warning like "x erroneous packages", the installation worked totally fine. However, while using the system for a few days now, I am facing some weird bugs that I never had before (using the same Ubuntu distribution). 
So I was wondering weather that may has something to do with the hardware I used for the installation. I thought that with the adapter, the SD-card would be equal to a USB-stick. 
 Does anyone know weather (and why) this could cause issues?

Comment: What issues are you having, specifically? Did you install Ubuntu on *this same device* in the past, or on a different device?

Comment: @Esther It's the same device. One issue is that sometimes after starting the computer, Ubuntu is not detecting any audio devices (input and output). Same goes for my camera. Also sometimes after starting, when I want to open a program (or even just the settings), it's not popping up the window. It shows up in the top bar beside "activities" and also shows up in the system monitor. Then after some time I get the "program not responding" error. Sometimes this even crashes the whole system temporary. Also I had some issues installing python packages, but that I got fixed.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting